# Is continuation with optional lock subject to a race condition?

Tags: .net, concurrency, task-parallel-library

I am just now getting started with the task parallel library.  The task in question is to process results in as parallel a manner as possible, but maintain the ordering of the results.

Also, an item can be added at any time until the flag is set indicating that no more items will be accepted.

Also, some clients will need to be notified once all results are completed (which will only occur once no more items are being accepted).

I have come up with the below simplified sample, which seems to work well in all my testing.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < random.Next(5, 21); ++i)
        {
            AddItem(i);
        }

        finishedAddingItems = true;

        completion.Task.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static TaskCompletionSource<bool> completion = 
                            new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    static bool finishedAddingItems = false;

    static Random random = new Random();

    class QueueResult
    {
        public int data;
        public int IsFinished;
    }

    static ConcurrentQueue<QueueResult> queue = 
                           new ConcurrentQueue<QueueResult>();

    static object orderingLockObject = new object();

    static void AddItem(int i)
    {
        var queueItem = new QueueResult { data = i, IsFinished = 0 };

        queue.Enqueue(queueItem);

        Task.Factory
            .StartNew(() => 
            { 
                for (int busy = 0; 
                     busy <= random.Next(9000000, 90000000); 
                     ++busy) 
                { }; 
                Interlocked.Increment(ref queueItem.IsFinished); 
            })
            .ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                QueueResult result;

                //the if check outside the lock is to avoid tying up resources
                //needlessly, since only one continuation can actually process
                //the queue at a time.
                if (queue.TryPeek(out result) 
                    && result.IsFinished == 1)
                {
                    lock (orderingLockObject)
                    {
                        while (queue.TryPeek(out result) 
                               && result.IsFinished == 1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(result.data);
                            queue.TryDequeue(out result);
                        }

                        if (finishedAddingItems && queue.Count == 0)
                        {
                            completion.SetResult(true);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

However, I am having trouble convincing myself whether or not there is a potential race condition where it is possible that an item would fail to get processed?

Comment: No, I am currently stuck at .NET 4.0

Comment: @Hans I *am* using ConcurrentQueue.  So I'm not sure whether your comment has any validity.

Comment: @Hans Also, if I understand your comment on the hot wait loop correctly, I am in fact *not* busy waiting, which is the whole point.  The  for (int busy = 0; ... loop is simply to simulate work for the purposes of the sample.

Comment: @HansPassant Wouldn't the TaskCompletionSource take the place of the AutoResetEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your code may not work correctly, because you didn't declare `IsFinished` as `volatile` and you're accessing it directly outside of a lock. In any case, using [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) correctly is hard, so you shouldn't do it unless you really have to.

Also, your code is also quite a mess (having everything in one class, using `int` instead of `bool`, unnecessary `ContinueWith()`, …) and contains at least one more thread-safety issue (`Random` is not thread-safe).

Because of all that, I suggest you learn about the more advanced parts of TPL. In your case, PLINQ sounds like the right solution:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, random.Next(5, 21)); // or some other collection

var results = source.AsParallel()
                    .AsOrdered()
                    .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
                    .Select(i => /* perform your work here */);

foreach (int i in results)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The problem with this is that (unless I misunderstand) this assumes I know the size of the results at the outset.  Which, I don't as stated in the outset of the question.  I'm modifying the sample code to make this more clear.

Comment: @Nathan In that case, you can use `BlockingCollection` together with `GetConsumingEnumerable()` as the source for the PLINQ query, instead of `Range()`. In other words, this doesn't assume you know the size of the collection, just that it's an `IEnumerable`. I have clarified the code.

Comment: Your PLINQ example combined with BlockingCollection and GetConsumingEnumerable() does exactly what I need, and even provides a way to indicate that no more results will be added.  Even better, it also runs a lot more efficiently than my first code attempt.